# pdf opens in browsers but when downloaded looks for password

Tags: 14.04, firefox, password, pdf, evince

When I open [this pdf file](http://www.cameramanuals.org/canon_pdf/canon_eos_1.pdf) in either Firefox or Opera it opens fine. If downloaded and I try to open in Ubuntu (evince or ocular) it looks for a password to open it. It opens fine in Windows without looking for a password.

I am happy to be able to read the pdf through my browser but I would like to know how to diagnose the file in Ubuntu to find out what is causing it to look for a password in Ubuntu only when downloaded.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? It appears you found at least one simple way to display the content of that file.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Curiosity more than anything. Just would like to understand why downloaded version makes ubuntu look for a password.

Comment: @DavidFoerster is that better?

Comment: I just tried the mentioned file, I can open the downloaded file with firefox, but not with the document viewer as the file seems to be protected. I tried the print-option in the browser and printed  to a file, took a moment, but I can open the created file in the document viewer.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/acrobat/pdfs/adobe-acrobat-xi-protect-pdf-file-with-permissions-tutorial-ue.pdf , I think this will explain the phenomen.

Comment: I'm having this problem too, with the Windows port of evince.

Comment: Apparently, if a password is required to edit the PDF, evince and some other readers act as though the same password is required to *open* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some PDFs can have certain restrictions which evince (the one in 14.04) can't correctly handle and It asks for password. The solution is using other pdf readers.

Opening with browsers works great. But if you're looking for ways to open with desktop application you may try `mupdf` and foxit pdf reader. Mupdf is very barebone pdf reader and very fast and somehow it can manage to open such pdfs.

```
sudo apt-get install mupdf
```

will install it.

You can download foxit reader from here https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/

Comment: `mupdf -p password file.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

Either of these command lines should create a PDF you can open in Evince. However, I have only tested them using Cygwin and Git Bash on Windows 10, with the Windows port of Evince:

```
qpdf --decrypt in.pdf out.pdf
```

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf
```

However, the gs command line wouldn't accept an output file path with the ~ character in, and its output file itself was much larger than the qpdf version. So I would recommend qpdf.

Note that neither of these command lines will work if opening the PDF really is password-protected. But they will allow you to work around the problem you're having and create files you can open in Evince.

Both command lines were taken from:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux

Hovever, the `gs` command line had to be altered by removing `-c .setpdfwrite -f`, since the `.setpdfwrite` operator was deprecated in version 9.53 and removed entirely in 9.54.

Comment: In response to the comment above, I've added the URL that was the source for my information, as well as some other information (since later changes to Ghostscript broke the original version of the gs command line.)